How can I insert self-referencing data with Sequelize?
I am trying to insert data into a table that references itself. Basically a folder structure; so a subfolder would have a parent id. When I execute the create statement it is only inserting the first record but none of the children. My question is, how do I insert data that references the same table and how can I select the data? Below is the code I have been working with.
Thank you for any help you can provide!
//-----entity.js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Entity = sequelize.define(
        'entity',
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                unique: true,
            },
            created_by: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: true,
            },
            created_at: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: new Date(),
            },
            parent_id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            },
            label: {
                type: DataTypes.TEXT,
                allowNull: false,
            },
        },
        {
            tableName: 'entity',
            timestamps: false,
            freezeTableName: true,
        },
    );

    return Entity;
};


//-----db.js (in part)
db.entity.hasOne(db.entity, {
    foreignKey: 'parent_id',
    as: 'parent',
    useJunctionTable: false,
});


//-----entity.service.js (in part)
const entities = await db.entity.create(
        {
            label: 'test',
            children: [{ label: 'another test' }],
        },
        {
            include: [entity],
        },
    );


Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. Also take the [tour].
